# Statistical distribution of crowdfunding donations?

Tags: distributions, modeling

Is there an accepted model for the statistical distribution of the size of crowdfunding contributions (be it simple donations or some sort of investment scheme)? Or at least some freely available data I could look at?

I've searched for it on Google using various terms but I didn't really find the information I was looking for. But I'd be surprised if it turned out nobody has ever looked into this.

Comment: Alas, questions about specific datasets aren't on-topic for this SE either. Once you obtain data, methods for fitting/estimating such a distribution would be on-topic.

Comment: For my learning: would the part asking about the expected shape of the distribution be on-topic? Maybe that would fit better on economics though...

Answer (score 1):

A rough and ready approach is this.  You have a random quantity which is always positive, sometimes huge, but frequently clustered around a small number (e.g., the mode is below the expectation).

A candidate for fitting this is the lognormal, which has exactly these properties.

The downside of this assumption is that the lognormal sort of presumes a feedback process which makes the SDE solve for it.  The fact the curve fits (or roughly fits) is nice, but doesn't justify the mechanism for why it is the right choice.

But lots of data is fit with a lognormal: the distribution of tree heights in a forest; the size of fish in a large school of fish, etc.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

This is also helpful for another perspective: [https://stat.ethz.ch/~stahel/lognormal/bioscience.pdf](https://stat.ethz.ch/%7Estahel/lognormal/bioscience.pdf)

Comment: It is difficult to imagine a forest whose tree heights approximate a lognormal distribution: that's unrealistic. This points out a fundamental logical issue with your answer: there are myriad distributions that meet the characterization in your first paragraph, but there's no reason to favor the lognormal over any of the others. The choice of a distributional family ought to depend either on experience analyzing such data or on some theory of the data generation process.  Without that, it's hard to characterize any answer as more than mere speculation.

Comment: Agreed 100%.  Hence my caveat: it's nice to have a mechanism that gives logical support to the distribution of choice, like an SDE.  And, that's why I included reference #2: they give a synopsis of places lognormal are presumed in the (life) sciences, even though the mechanism might be suspect.

Comment: How would you formulate an SDE for crowdfunding contributions??

Comment: I don't have any idea.  Just my observation that we often fit to a distribution that has the right characteristics, including when there is no clever underlying model.  It's of course better when you have such a model, but that never stopped anyone doing otherwise.  After all, much of financial (stock price) modeling is done from the assumption returns are normally distributed and follow a arithmetic brownian motion, even though that surely is wrong - and a lognormal does fit there logically based on the SDE.